# how to include mysql db inside eclipse project

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a dynamic web java project, which needs to talk to a database

i want to include the created database file inside the project, so that i can access the data inside and the db isnt on some server

is it possible to do that? if so, how ?

Comment: Check this out:- http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Setup_MySQL_DB_in_Eclipse

Comment: I am no database expert, so take what I say with a grain of salt, but you can use an embedded Java database such as Apache Derby (also called Java DB, I think), or H2, but I don't think that the data files likely should be held by the jar file since this will make it read only.

Answer (score 1):

For eclipse, open view Data Source Explorer and add the database.